# Data exchange between Rails applications

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

For learning purposes I have developed two rails applications - one is like a book store, where users can go and buy books and the other one is like delivery company, which delivers these books.

And the idea is that user orders book in the book store, and the delivery form data, from this store is sent to the delivery application. I hope you got the idea. For example, both apps are on production server(like heroku).

Are there any suggestions how to do that? I couldn't find anygood information on the web.

My first thought was to render .json from book store, but then, how could I get this information to my delivery site? Or maybe you have better suggestions for me?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: You could do a post request to your json based web service. Also look at my answer below & explore message brokers.

Answer (score 2):

There are a couple of ways you can do this.

#### 1. Web Services

[Here's](http://railscasts.com/episodes/409-active-model-serializers) a wonderful railscast which will help you build a rest based JSON API using ActiveModel serializers.

These ([versioning](http://railscasts.com/episodes/350-rest-api-versioning) / [protection](http://railscasts.com/episodes/352-securing-an-api?view=asciicast)) railscasts will help you version & protect your API.

#### 2. Message Broker like [rabbitmq](http://www.rabbitmq.com/).

The [bunny](https://github.com/ruby-amqp/bunny) gem makes it easy to interact with Rabbitmq. Consider using it.

Comment: I have created the JSON API for the application A. But how can I access that data from application B? I searched internet on how to make requests but didn't find anything useful. Maybe you have any suggestions?

Comment: In application B, use a library like NetHTTP or openURI to call application A's web service URL.

Answer (score 1):

Try to use [ActiveResource](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveResource/Base.html)
It allows you to easily communicate between multiple Rails applications.